# ES6 (Babel) - cannot call super.methodName of an extended class outside the class definition

Tags: javascript, inheritance, ecmascript-6, super, babeljs

So, I understand that I can use super() within the child class to call a function defined on the base class. However, if I want to call that object's super method elsewhere, it bombs

Parent.js

```
class Parent {
    yell() {
        console.log('yell')
    }
}
```

Child.js

```
class Child extends Parent {
     shout() {
         super.yell() //this works
     }
}


Child.super.yell() //this doesnt work
```

Comment: `Child` isn’t an instance of `Child` and `super` isn’t a property. Do you want `new Child().yell()`?

Comment: Whoops, yeah lemme fix that.  EDIT: Ok yeah, that worked. Thanks!

Comment: `super` is specially, pretty much like `this`. It's not a property of the instances. It also doesn't make much sense from an engineering point of view. A caller should not make any assumption about the inheritance chain of an object. It should only be concerned about its interface.

Comment: @minitech I'd like to make your answer the accepted answer, but I don't know if that's possible since it's a comment..?

Comment: @FelixKling Ahhh wow yeah, makes much more sense now that you put it that way. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you want to call a `super` method on an instance, either don't implement the method in the child class (which will default to calling the `super` method) or call `super.methodName()` within the child class method implementation.

Additionally, you are trying to call a method on the class itself rather than an instance, if this is your goal, you need to make the method `static`:

```
class Parent {
    static yell() {
        console.log('yell')
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {

}

Child.yell();
```

Answer (score 4):

It might help to take a look at the transpiled code that babel outputs:

```
'use strict';

var _get = function get(_x, _x2, _x3) { var _again = true; _function: while (_again) { var object = _x, property = _x2, receiver = _x3; desc = parent = getter = undefined; _again = false; var desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(object, property); if (desc === undefined) { var parent = Object.getPrototypeOf(object); if (parent === null) { return undefined; } else { _x = parent; _x2 = property; _x3 = receiver; _again = true; continue _function; } } else if ('value' in desc) { return desc.value; } else { var getter = desc.get; if (getter === undefined) { return undefined; } return getter.call(receiver); } } };

var _createClass = (function () { function defineProperties(target, props) { for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) { var descriptor = props[i]; descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false; descriptor.configurable = true; if ('value' in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true; Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor); } } return function (Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) { if (protoProps) defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps); if (staticProps) defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps); return Constructor; }; })();

function _inherits(subClass, superClass) { if (typeof superClass !== 'function' && superClass !== null) { throw new TypeError('Super expression must either be null or a function, not ' + typeof superClass); } subClass.prototype = Object.create(superClass && superClass.prototype, { constructor: { value: subClass, enumerable: false, writable: true, configurable: true } }); if (superClass) subClass.__proto__ = superClass; }

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError('Cannot call a class as a function'); } }

var Parent = (function () {
    function Parent() {
        _classCallCheck(this, Parent);
    }

    _createClass(Parent, [{
        key: 'yell',
        value: function yell() {
            console.log('yell');
        }
    }]);

    return Parent;
})();

var Child = (function (_Parent) {
    function Child() {
        _classCallCheck(this, Child);

        if (_Parent != null) {
            _Parent.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    }

    _inherits(Child, _Parent);

    _createClass(Child, [{
        key: 'shout',
        value: function shout() {
            _get(Object.getPrototypeOf(Child.prototype), 'yell', this).call(this);
        }
    }]);

    return Child;
})(Parent);
```

There's a few important things here:

- the methods you defined are added to the class's prototype
- the Child prototype is an *instance* of the Parent class
- calling super grabs the function of the same name from the prototype

So in order to call yell you can do one of a few things:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(_Child)).yell.call(_Child)
```

or

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(Child.prototype).yell.call(_Child)
```

or, and I recommend this one:

```
Parent.prototype.yell.call(_Child)
```